Using PostgreSQL-Specific SQL Syntax in Apache Calcite (e.g., DISTINCT ON, GROUP BY {position})
I recently resolved an issue I was facing with PostgreSQL-specific SQL functions in Apache Calcite by setting the fun=postgresql parameter in the connection string, thanks to the solution provided in this post. I'm using Calcite version 1.37.0.
While this setting allowed me to use PostgreSQL-specific functions like TO_TIMESTAMP, I'm running into issues with other PostgreSQL-specific SQL syntax, for example:

DISTINCT ON: I'm unable to use this syntax, which is commonly used
in PostgreSQL to return the first row of each set of rows that share
the same value(s) in the specified columns.

GROUP BY {position}: This syntax, which allows grouping by the
position of a column in the SELECT list, also doesn't seem to be
supported even with the fun=postgresql setting.


Has anyone successfully enabled support for these PostgreSQL-specific syntaxes in Apache Calcite? If so, how did you achieve it? Is there a specific configuration or extension needed, or are these features currently unsupported in Calcite? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Details:
Calcite Version: 1.37.0
Setting Used: fun=postgresql in the connection properties
Thank you!

DISTINCT ON can be replaced by using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(). GROUP BY {position} is something I wouldn't use for production code: Most people are unfamiliar with this, and any change in your code could result in unwanted outcomes.
